# Start with U, add another U, remove the U - what is the word?

Tags: wordplay

1. Start with "U".
2. Add another "U".
3. Remove the "U".

What is the word?

**Hint:** It's not "U" (or "you", "ewe", etcetera).

Comment: [Bird is the word!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPrtFxd9u9Y) Also, congrats for Hot Network Question!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Double

Because:

1. You start with U.
2. You add another U, so you get

> UU - a double U (W).

3. You remove a U, and you're stuck with

> double.

Comment: Nicely done! That was the first riddle I came up with myself :D Thanks for verifying it.

Comment: It was a nice riddle, next time you might want to wait a few hours before accepting an answer because it gives other users a chance to answer something else that might fit ;)

Comment: Ahh fair enough, I'll keep that in mind for next time. Thanks.

Comment: @Jordy But a good riddle should have only one answer that fits everything properly.